# "Game On" room doesn't show up under the Gaming.SE chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

The ["Game On" room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/271/se-game-on) doesn't show up with the other [gaming themed rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=gaming.stackexchange.com), can this be remedied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Game On is supposed to be an SE wide event (we at least *used* to have a large representation from SU), and thus is associated with Meta Stack Overflow.

That is changing and changing associations with Gaming is increasingly reasonable.

---

Today marked the fourth week in a row with no participation outside of Gaming. Change applied.